# Creating ruby gem out of swig generated cxx wrapper

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, swig

I have now spent days on this. WHAT am I doing wrong?!

I have a swig generated wrapper for a c++ library I'm interested in using (COIN-OR). So I wrote a c++ struct that has all the methods I need from coin, and I have written a Swig interface file awcbc.i. I then wrapped it with swig, and this generated a awcbc_wrapper.cxx file.

I have an extconf.rb file, which creates a makefile from this. I included the necessary libraries like this:

```
with_cflags("-x c++") do
    abort 'missing cbc' unless find_library("Cbc", nil, "lib")
    abort 'missing CbcModel.hpp' unless find_header("CbcModel.hpp", "include/coin")
    abort 'missing awcbc.hpp' unless find_header("awcbc.hpp", "include")
end
```

"lib" is full of dylibs, one of which is Cbc. Similarly, CbcModel.hpp is one of the many headers in include/coin. The point of these is to include those directories, and thus all my dependencies into the search path. awcbc.hpp contains my struct.

When I run

```
$ ruby extconf.rb; make;
```

it creates a makefile and compiles it. I can then run irb, require awcbc, and it's all there and working.

However, when I try to put some of this into a rakefile (I've tried Jeweller, following the format set by a very similar library heroku-rglpk, or tried to use rake-compiler, as described in [ruby-guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/), I get

```
ERROR:  Error installing ./pkg/awcbc-0.0.0.gem:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/*...*/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lCbc... no
missing cbc
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

But it didn't fail when I called ruby extconf.rb manually!

This is one out of several nightmares in getting this fairly simple extension built. 
What I'm shooting for, is a gem that I can put on ruby-gems which is basically the exact same thing as heroku-rglpk. I want it to check for Coin-Or, install if not there, wrap it, and gemify it. It's so frustrating that I can make the wrapper, and use it, but then I can't gemify it (and incidentally, this means I have NO IDEA how to include it in my rails app).

Bah. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hah, not provocative. The comments were unintentional. They were accidental repetition of the question and I thought they'd been deleted. When writing the question I was thinking "this will never be answered, it's too long and specific". But I couldn't figure out how to cut it down so rolled with it anyway. Thanks for the suggestions mins.